# Lock the user in an activity

Tags: java, android, locking

My app contains lessons and a quiz about those lessons.

I want to implement a quiz in my app wherein if they would like to take it, they must agree on one condition that they aren't allowed to go back to the lessons.

Meaning to say, I want them to be locked in that particular activity which has the quiz even if they turn off the application or their cellphones.

I could not seem to find any solutions to it apparently, a help is appreciated!

Comment: This is rather open-ended,  please provided more of a context, and tools you are using to build your app.

Comment: I'm using android studio and java. Used the navigation drawer preset. I already have a quiz fragment with a button which would lead to the quiz activity.

Comment: Basically, I just need help on how would I implement the code in order to lock someone in my quiz activity even if they turn off the application or their phone (if that's even possible.)